# What are the Scriptures that talk about Rukmini's love and letter before marriage with krishna?

Tags: scripture, krishna, bhagavata-purana, rukmini

Consider the [following lines](https://www.mea.gov.in/Images/attach/amb/Volume_04.pdf#page=358) in **THE RIDDLE OF RAMA AND KRISHNA** by *Babasaheb Dr. B.R. Ambedkar* regarding the marriage of Rukmini with Krishna

> Krishna was now, for the first time, married. He married Rukmini,
> daughter of Bhishmaka, king of Vidarbha. Her father, at Jarasandha’s
> advice, was making preparations to get her married to Sishupala,
> Krishna’s cousin and king of Chedi. But Krishna carried her off on the
> day before the proposed marriage. **The Bhagavata says she had fallen
> in love with Krishna and had addressed a love letter to him. This does
> not seem to be true.** For Krishna did not remain a true and faithful
> husband of Rukmini. Rukmini was gradually followed by an enormously
> vast army of co-wives till the number of Krishna’s consorts rose to
> sixteen thousand one hundred and eight. His children numbered one lakh
> and eighty-thousand.

In these lines, Ambedkar is saying that it seems untrue to him that Rukmini fell in love with Krishna and addressed a love letter to Krishna. I know a scripture other than Baghavatham that writes Rukmini's fall in love and writing a letter to Krishna

> From my mouth she once heard the transcendental virtues of Lord
> Krishna. From that day she thought of attaining a husband like Him,
> the Supreme Personality of Godhead............... Rukmi thought his
> sister should be given to Shishupala, a great warrior who was
> Krishna's enemy. Dejected, Rukmini sent a brahmana messenger to
> noble-hearted Lord Krishna.
>
> [[4-8, 4: Journey to the City of Kundina, Canto 6, Garga Samhitha]](https://wikikrishna.com/index.php?title=GS_6.4:_Journey_to_the_City_of_Kundina)

Garga Samhitha is not written by Vyasa and was written by Garga. Are there any writings *other than Vyasa's* that mention Rukmini's love for Krishna before marriage and writing a letter to Krishna?

Comment: have we now resorted to talking about the opinions of a guy who said *"I was born a Hindu but I won't die one"* ? Bramhater is a famous anti-hindu.

Comment: @mar **have we now resorted to talking about the opinions of a guy** Not exactly. But answers to these are very useful as many people read those books and form opinions based on the statements in those books. Don't you like these sorts of questions?

Comment: If you have the doubt, that's fine. But what's point in quoting some rando's opinions. that too from an established intellectually-dishonest-bad-faith actor like him. There are a million nastiks who have weird interpretations of scriptures. No need to quote their source. Answers need references; questions, not so much.

Comment: hA @mar the purpose of quoting is that, in the recent past, I read some questions on our main site asking "why there are no answers for criticisms made by Ambedkar?". I think the question is deleted now. So, If new users search for answers based on popular books like this, I think that these are useful enough. Anyways, I will ask from more users before doing. Thanks.